# How do you manage individual repository access based on users in mercurial on iis?

Tags: iis, mercurial

I have followed the instructions here https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories. I have the site serving 3 test repositories.

I don't want every repository to be access by everyone. I want certain repositories to only be accessed by certain users.

How do you manage the granular access to each mercurial repository using the hgweb on iis?

Comment: Based on this http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories#Public_and_Private_Repositories I'm assuming that using IIS and hgweb you would have to setup separate links/domains and assign permissions per each link for each repository. I'm guessing that would also mean setting up your own dashboard for all these links/domains?